# python selenium SessionNotCreatedException error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Facing problem from selenium

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/SONY/PycharmProjects/untitled/bot_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

  File "C:\Users\SONY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

  File "C:\Users\SONY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\SONY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\SONY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\SONY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79`

Comment: If the error weren't so incredibly obvious, this would be severely lacking in information on the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your **ChromeDriver** is not compatible with **chrome browser**

Check your chrome browser version and download chrome driver from [this](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) site.

And set the path of chrome driver in your code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('E:\\Om\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
```

you need to be give path of chrome driver.

Steps :-

1. Find your chrome version (Help-> About Google Chrome)
2. Find your chromedriver version, if you already have one. (For me "chromedriver.exe -v" gave me the version on windows environment.)
3. Visit the official chrome webdriver page [link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
4. Download the chromedriver matching your chrome browser version, from the above download location.
5. You can put the downloaded chromedriver binary in the path environment.
6. Set path in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Error says that you are using incompatible `chromedriver` for your `chrome` version. Please download matching version of `chromedriver` for your `Chrome` version from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads